# Writing string to text file in C (extra blank space in the beginning of file)

Tags: c, string, file

I have a problem with writing a string to text file and reading it from file.

Input string (`char text1`) writes to the file (`input.txt`) correctly and reads too.
But I have a problem with the result file - the string seems to write to file correctly, but if I take a look at file, there is a blank space before the result string in file at the beginning. If I input text "`weather is weather`" then in the result file I have this - 
"`weather is is weather`". The result string text is ok, the only problem is that for some reason, there is a blank space at the beginning of the result file.

When I print the contents of result file on the screen with this code

```
while((ch2 = fgetc(result)) != EOF)
        printf("%c", ch2);
```

it prints nothing, but if I print the `text2` string itself (not from file) with `puts(text2);` then it prints correctly.

What could be the cause of this problem and how could I solve it?

Here's the whole program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


int main()
{
    char text1[200], text2[200], words[20][100], *dist, ch1, ch2;
    int i, j, nwords=0;

    FILE *input, *result;

    input = fopen("input.txt", "w");

    if(input == NULL)
    {
        perror("Error opening the file.\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);         
    }

// Text input

    printf("\n Enter the text:\n\n   ");
    gets(text1);
    fputs(text1, input);
    fclose(input);


// Split string into words

    dist = strtok(text1, " ,.!?");
    i=0;
    while(dist!=0)
    {      
        strcpy(words[i],dist);
        dist = strtok(NULL, " ,.!?");
        i++;
        nwords++;                
    }


// Duplicating words that doesn't repeat in input string and copy them into tex2 string

    int flag_arr[20];
    memset(flag_arr, 0, 20);

    for(i=0; i <= nwords-1; i++)
    {
        for(j=0; j<=nwords-1; j++)
        {
            if(strcmp(words[i],words[j])==0)
            {
                flag_arr[i] += 1;
            }
        }
    }

    for(i = 0; i <=nwords-1; i++)
    {
        if(flag_arr[i] > 1)
        {
            strcat(text2," ");
            strcat(text2,words[i]);                              
        }
        else
        {
            strcat(text2," ");
            strcat(text2,words[i]);
            strcat(text2," ");
            strcat(text2,words[i]);
        }
    }

    result = fopen("result.txt", "w");

    if(result == NULL)
    {
        perror("Error opening the file.\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);         
    }

    fputs(text2, result);
    fclose(result);


// Rezultats

    fopen("input.txt", "r");
    if(input == NULL)
    {
        perror("Error opening the file.\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);         
    }
    fopen("result.txt", "r");
    if(result == NULL)
    {
        perror("Error opening the file.\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);         
    }

    printf("\n\n\n Input:\n\n   ");
    while((ch1 = fgetc(input)) != EOF)
        printf("%c", ch1);
//    puts(input);

    printf("\n\n\n Result:\n\n  ");
    while((ch2 = fgetc(result)) != EOF)
        printf("%c", ch2);   
//    puts(text2);

    fclose(input);
    fclose(result);

    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: increment `i` in one of your blocks. (see answer below...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because `stdout` is *buffered*. Either add a newline to your printing, or explicitly flush the buffer with

```
fflush(stdout);
```

---

You have this line

```
input = fopen("input.txt", "w");
```

And this line (two times, once is enough)

```
fopen("input.txt", "r");
```

Nowhere do you actually *reassign* the `input` variable. This means that when you attempt to read from `input` you will get an error (which you do not report) as you try to read from a write-only file handle.

Comment: I added it  - "fflush(stdout); while((ch2 = fgetc(result)) != EOF)
        printf("%c", ch2);", but the result is still the same - nothing.

Comment: @Kurbads You need to flush *after* you print.

Comment: After the while loop or in while loop?  I tried both (after loop and in loop), but still the same - it prints nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding your statement:  *then in the result file I have this* - ***"weather is is weather".***
In this block:

```
   else
    {
        strcat(text2," ");
        strcat(text2,words[i]);
        strcat(text2," ");
        strcat(text2,words[i]); //(change this to  strcat(text2,words[i+1]);)
    }
```

It looks like you are not incrementing i, and so will get the same word twice, separated by a space, `" "`.

By the way, this suggests that your file is fine, rather it is the way you are presenting the buffers after having extracted them that's the problem.

Comment: The actual task of this program was to duplicate words that doesn't repeat in input string. And for those words that repeat in the string, just copy them "as is" to the result string, so the result string text is ok. I only have problems with reading the result string from the file. For some unknown (for me) reason there is a blank space at the beggining of the result file and I think that causing the problems, so I can't read the result string properly from file.

Answer (score 0):

I realize the original problem is quite old, however I found the advice lacking and wanted to leave behind something more useful for understanding....
The most important issue with your program is one that the other programmers did not address.  You must initialize text2.
You used strcat with text2 without first initializing text2.  In other words you concatenated the contents of your pointer with text2, but text2 never had any value, so what was printed to screen (or file) was left over garbage.
The fact that your program worked after flushing has little to do with flushing but rather the random effects of memory.

```
char text1[20] = "";
char text2[20] = "";
```

Solves half the problem.  The other issue is minor regarding when to put the spaces between words.

```
for(i = 0; i <=nwords-1; i++)
{
    if(flag_arr[i] > 1)
    {
        strcat(text2,words[i]); // Check out the ordering here.
        strcat(text2," ");
    }
    else
    {
        strcat(text2,words[i]);
        strcat(text2," ");
        strcat(text2,words[i]);
        strcat(text2," ");
    }
}
```